# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. when using webclient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to upload an image to an imagehost  http://uploads.im/.

According to its very short API http://uploads.im/apidocs this is a way of doing that:

http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png
Note that in this example he is uploading an image from the internet and I'm trying to upload a file from my computer.

The result I wish to get back is a response from the server containing the `href` to the image I just uploaded.

This is the code someone here provided:

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\sack.png";



 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
         try
                    {
                        byte[] response = client.UploadFile("http://uploads.im/api?upload",filepath);
                        string s = client.Encoding.GetString(response);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
    }
```

I get error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

That allowed med to see this, is this what you are after?
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Size of Image, time after exception failed, etc.

Comment: The size of the file is 96kb,,I dont know how to see time after exception, could you maybe explain how to do that?

Comment: First of all - you should wrap your code with try/catch statement, to get more info about error.

Comment: I wrapped the code in try/catch, plase see edit

Comment: Are you sure that there is no firewall which blocks your requests?

Comment: I tried it again with firewall turned off..same result...But you are saying the the code looks alright and should work?

Comment: I've just tested this code and it returned 502 error for me.

Comment: Weird that we are getting different errors..

Comment: You can try to find problem inside StackTrace.